# Editing text in ActionScript file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new to Flash, so my apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

I'm editing a Flash file that someone else created. When I open the corresponding .as file (in Flash CS 5.5), I find the text I want to edit in green, make the necessary updates, and save. Then, I open the .fla file, republish the .swf, and replace the previous .swf file. The problem is that the Flash file no longer works after I go through these steps. The click-able first scene does not respond.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Does it have to do with the way I'm editing the ActionScript file?

Comment: There are a number reasons why it could not work: Does it compile properly before you edited the file?  If it doesn't, are you compiling to the same player version that the original did?  If it did compile properly, did you write your code properly (you'd want to share that portion, btw).  At this point, you haven't provided enough info to help you.

Comment: Since string are by default green in flash pro .as files, the I assume your only changing some of the strings in the file. If this is so then it is impossible for your changing of the string to affect the application, and so it must be something else your doing. And since you have not provided any other information, then no one can possible answer this question.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, it is very possible to affect the functionality of an application by just editing a string value if that string is a setting of some sort. For example, if the application expects the string to contain either "red" or "blue" and it's changed to "green."